# PHP Array of weekdays Monday through Sunday - change first day keep order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So here's my array:

```
array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
```

How could I change the starting day to say:

```
array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
```

This is probably ridiculously easy but my brain hurts from trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next code snippet (two lines in fact):

```
$days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");

// Remove the last element "Sunday" from the array
$lastDay = array_pop($days); 
  
// Append the last day at the beginning of the array
$days = [$lastDay, ...$days];

print_r($days);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aRJ8H)

Comment: Can be made into one line `$days = [ array_pop($days), ...$days ]` .

Comment: @apokryfos, yeap, it's obvious. But for debugging these two lines are better.

Comment: This is helpful but what if I need to start with Thursday? I take it there's no function to shift the array? Will I need to just write a function to rework the array based on which day I need to show first?

Comment: @David, in-built function - no, but a custom function could be created.